# Discrete choice prediction

Tags: logistic, multivariate-analysis

I have a set of images of same color cars which I have users rate on a scale from 1-5 (integers only) based on how attractive they think the car design is. For each image I have a set of parameters about the cars in question, mostly various ratios of dimensions (say height at middle, width at trunk, curviness of hood, etc). I first give the user a set of training images and have them rate them. I would like to use this training set to predict future ratings by a particular user based on the ratios of the car in question. While a number prediction would be great (ie a prediction of what the user will rate the car), I am also willing to settle on a predicting of whether the rating is above or below say, 3. I don't really have a background in stats, but I think this has something to do with logistic regressions and discrete choice? I was wondering what a good reference for this would be.

To add a little more info, there are no strong individual correlations amongst the ratios and the users rating. Moreover, a linear regression is out of the question because there isn't a simple relationship between changing a particular ratio and the attractiveness. Moreover, I also do not want to intoduce too many ratios because then they become correlated with each other (say, height/width and height/length can give length/width upon division).

Comment: You coud use logistic or ordinal logistic regression, but if Linear regression isn't useful I don't think logistic or ordinal logistic will be. I think people from data mining/machine learning area may help you here. My guess is that other variables (Related to individual characteristics of raters) can be more relevant.

Comment: @ sam -- with my limited background in this field,I dont see any reason why you shouldnt use logistic regression here. I think for predicting the final rating a linear regression shouldnt be used. An ordinal logistic regression should be of use here. For the second question whether the rating is >3 or less, this seems to be case of normal logistic regression where the > 3 should be termed as 1 and <= 3 as 0. Relevant variables should be used then to predict the dichotomous outcome.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is called [Conjoint Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoint_analysis_%28marketing%29) . "Multivariate Data Analysis" by Hair has a good chapter on this.

[[Discrete] Choice Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_modelling) is when you have the user compare two (or three) images at once, and ask them to choose their preferred one. In this case you would use *conditional* logistic regression, or a hierarchical bayesian model, to analyze the results.

[Sawtooth software](http://www.sawtoothsoftware.com/) has a good package, for both conjoint and choice, and [JMP has a nice Choice Modeling package](http://www.jmp.com/software/jmp8/demos.shtml), which uses the bayes technique. Neither are cheap, though JMP has a 30 day trial, and is remarkably discounted if you are associated with a college/university.